# Give local file access to Webserver

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack-dev-server

I just began learning JavaScript and I have been trying to upload a file to a webserver I am locally hosting. I am using a webpack JS file to start the server and the command "npm run dev" but I think I have something misconfigured as I can't upload local files to the webserver. I know that Google Chrome has that security feature where it stops you from accessing local files but I ran chrome with the required arguments to disable that security feature but it didn't work so I guess it's my server. This is what I am trying to do:

```
let uploadFile = document.createElement("input");
uploadFile.type = "file"
uploadFile.id = "inputFile"
uploadFile.innerText = "Upload File"
document.body.appendChild(uploadFile)
let fake_path
uploadFile.onchange = function () {
    fake_path = uploadFile.value
    alert(fake_path)
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( fake_path, function ( gltf ) {
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
    } );
};`
```

This is my webpack common file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/client.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.(glb)$/i,
                type: 'src/client/',
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            three: path.resolve('./node_modules/three')
        },
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.glb'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../dist/client'),
    }
};
```

And this is my Dev file:

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')
const path = require('path');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/client/'),

        },
        hot: true,
    },
})
```

Am I doing something wrong or why can't i access a local file? This is the error that
Chrome is giving me:
[image: Chrome Error]

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be operating under several different misapprehensions here. Here are the facts which contradict them:

1. The Webpack dev server does not support file uploads.
2. While you are using a file input to let the user select a local file, you aren't doing anything to try to upload it to the server
3. The `value` of a file input is only useful to telling the user the filename, you are trying to use it as a URL (which the webpack dev server can't resolve it to anything useful)

You need to pass an actual URL to `loader.load`. Not the `fake_path` you get from the `value` of a file input.

You can use `FileReader` to read the file and create a `data:` scheme URL from it. [This blog entry explains how](https://pqina.nl/blog/convert-a-file-to-a-base64-string-with-javascript/).

> ```
> <input type="file" />
>
> <script>
>     // Get a reference to the file input
>     const fileInput = document.querySelector('input');
>
>     // Listen for the change event so we can capture the file
>     fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
>         // Get a reference to the file
>         const file = e.target.files[0];
>
>         // Encode the file using the FileReader API
>         const reader = new FileReader();
>         reader.onloadend = () => {
>             console.log(reader.result);
>             // Logs data:<type>;base64,wL2dvYWwgbW9yZ...
>         };
>         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
>     });
> </script>
> ```

You then need to replace `console.log(reader.result);` with your call to `loader.load` (replacing `fake_path` with `reader.result`).

Comment: ,files does not exist for me somehow. I am using Intellij Ultimate. Do I have to import something so file[] and .file works?